Run method when variable changes in lwc
I simply want to run a method when a variable changes. I think @track monitors the changes, but how do I run this method when it does? How do I write this?
 @track displayedData <---when this changes by any means, I want the below thing to run.

 handleDisplayedDataChanged() {
        console.log('run'); 
    }


You'll want to use a getter-setter:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-props-getters-setters.html
@track is only needed if the variable is an object or array:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_track.htm&release=224&type=5
Edit: so your code would be:
   displayedDataVar; //gave it a unique name

  @api
  get displayedData() {
    return this.displayedDataVar;
  }
  set displayedData(value) {
    this.displayedDataVar= value;
    console.log('run'); 
  }

Edit2: apologies, I see that the example code was wrong, and have corrected it!
See code below on how to use displayedData variable:
connectedCallback(){
    displayedData = 'some string value'; //this will print 'run' in the console
}


thanks! where are you using displayedDataVar?

You should think of that as a placeholder. You just use displayedData as if it is a normal variable.

I think connect callback only runs before rendering the component, where as I was hoping for any time the variable changes. But perhaps the element that uses it has events that do this? Idk

The connected callback was just an example of where you could use it. This will also work if any other function/logica changes the value. :)
